# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization when importing redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I cannot import redux store from store.js to customAxios.js file.
I need to send token to backend which resides in redux store. So I need to extract that token, then add into axios Header.

Steps I followed

1. Created a store.js file which exports redux store.
2. Imported redux store from store.js in customAxios.js.

This is giving error: Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization.

[github_repo](https://github.com/asamad35/socio-plus/tree/main/frontend)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE1Xs.png)

**index.js**

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import store from "./redux/store";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
</BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
);
```

**customAxios.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { BASE_URL } from "./apiUrls";
import store from "../redux/store";

// console.log(store, "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");

export const customAxios = axios.create({ baseURL: BASE_URL });
```

**store.js**

```
import logger from "redux-logger";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = configureStore({
reducer: rootReducer,
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger),
devTools: true,
});

export default store;
```